# Converting Java Object -> JavaScript -> Reading from Applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I'm a bit stuck with this concept that I've been working on and I'm looking for some sort of guide on this.
Essentially this is the problem:

Bean retrieves data from database and I need to store it as a hidden field on a webpage.
The user then must authenticate the data using an applet.
The resulting authenticated object is then sent to the database.

So i'm stuck at this paradigm:

Bean -> Html & Javascript -> Applet

I think I can figure out the upload issue later, thanks :)

**Edit:** Switch Authenticate with Sign :)

**Edit2:**
It seems I have some data using JSObject but how do I retrieve the data from the JSObject?  The data was stored as a DataHandler before it was read by javascript and acquired by the applet.  I'm looking into the getClass() method call from the JSObject but it gives me an HTMLInputElement and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: *"The resulting authenticated object is then sent to the database."* From the client? You can't trust basically *anything* you receive from the client (from an applet or otherwise), you must authenticate it on the server. Perhaps it's a terminology thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you chose to use Applets, but from recent JDKs onwards (I think its JDK 1.6 not sure) an Applet has access to the Javascript variables and HTML DOM. So yes you can do it... you might want to ask yourself why you want to go down this route though.

Some more info:

The JSObject class helps you access Javascript from a Java applet. http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/docs/jsobject.html

Update: Actually its much older than JDK 1.6
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html

If you need to access the HTML structure of the page you can also access the DOM in the same way.

Comment: Applets are a requirement :(.  After a bit of research I'm looking into using the JSObject method.  I'll keep this updated with my findings.  Thanks!:D

Comment: It seems I have some data using JSObject but how do I retrieve the data from the JSObject?  The data was stored as a DataHandler before it was read by javascript and acquired by the applet.  I'm looking into the getClass() method call from the JSObject but it gives me an HTMLInputElement and I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: If it is as you're saying a Hidden Field in the web page, it is indeed an HTMLInputElement. In fact if you do a view source of your generated HTML in your browser you will find <input type="hidden" name="XXX"... />. HTML doesn't know about your DataHandler Java class, which is I suppose at the server side.